# TableView Cell как кнопка

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Как использовать ячейку в таблице (статистической) как кнопку, как на скрине.
https://pp.vk.me/c617926/v617926663/8faa/fJU_h4wsEGA.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при нажатии на ячейку срабатывает метод `UITableViewDelegate`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

его и можно использовать как хандлер нажатия